# How to use a string as a function in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, math

So I was trying to create a function that would put the value of i and j in a string as if it was a function.
Lets say that we have a string = "i+j"

what i want is:

> sum = sum + i + j

but currently what happens is

> sum = sum + "i + j"

**anyone got a solution for this?**

Comment: Use `evil`. Wait, I typed `eval`, but somehow it changed...

Comment: In a string or get variables from string and add it to sum variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing a function that "solves" an equation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448800/writing-a-function-that-solves-an-equation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i = 5,
    j = 10,
    string = "i+j",
    sum = 100;

sum = sum + eval(string);

console.log(sum); // output 115
```

Answer (score -1):

use parseInt() :

```
sum = sum + parseInt(i) + parseInt(j)
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully. The OP has the string `"i + j"` and wants to evaluate it. `parseInt` does not help here.